# How can I assign an icon to users depending on their gender?

Tags: 7, media, comments

I'd like comments on my website to look like this:

[image: Up: comment by a male. Down: comment by a female.]

Every comment has to be preceded by an image, depending on the gender of the user who wrote the comment. Users can choose Male/Female as their gender when they register, so the icon can't be changed: it's only related to the gender. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it ok for you to use user profile image for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, I have no intentions to use the profile image for other purposes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vocab as gender and add two taxonomies to it as male and female. To the gender vocab add image field and while creating the male and female taxonomy term add the respective images.

Now add the term reference file to user entity and keep it as stele list.

In your custom module hook_user_presave and get the value for the taxonomy field.when you know the selected taxonomy you can load the taxonomy to get the image field fid associated with it assign the fid to $user->picture.

Now everywhere image will load as per the gender selected.

Comment: Let me know if this workflow looks good to you I'll add some snippets which can be helpful

Comment: I followed your first paragraph: I succesfully created a new Taxonomy with the Terms 'male' and 'female', which have an image. Can you explain your second step a bit, please? I don't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: let me check if I can have you on chat

Comment: nice solution arpitr, but is it not so that usage of profile picture is a bit redundant here? I mean we can just grab the tid from the taxonomy term reference field, load the taxonomy term and grab the picture value with simple 3 lines of code. this will also keep an option open if they want to use the user picture for something else later ( I know he already said that he do not intend to use user picture).